# Using an array of true/false values to show/hide elements with v-show

Tags: vue.js

I have an array of DIVs that I need to show on a rotating basis:

```
  <div v-for="(part, index) in verses" :key="index"
       v-show="showSlides[index]">
    <pre>{{ part }}</pre>
  </div>
```

Here is the relevant vue.js code:

```
  data: {
    verses: ['first line', 'second line'],
    showSlides: [true, false]
  },
  methods: {
    show (slideNo) {
        for (let index = 0; index < this.showSlides.length; index++) {
          this.showSlides[index] = false
        }
        this.showSlides[slideNo] = true
    }
  }
```

It works fine initially (showing the first line, but not the second), but when I run the *show* method to change the *showSlides* array, it doesn't have any effect.

A **Codepen** can be found here: https://codepen.io/matthiku/pen/aYLjOx?editors=1111

Why is this not working as expected? Is this a problem with reactivity and object / array modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set your `data` like this.

```
data () {
  return {
    verses: [
      { name: 'first line', show: true }, 
      { name: 'second line', show: false }
    ]
  }
}
```

In your `div` for-loop, loop true and get the value for `show` in `verses`

```
<div v-for="verse in verses" :key="verse.name" v-show="verse.show">
  <pre>{{ verse }}</pre>
</div>
```

This method makes your code so much cleaner than having to add more things to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ru Chern Chong's answer is perfectly fine, but I also found another solution that doesn't require me to change the array of "DIV"s into an object (my code example is just a small part of a much bigger project).

So instead of this line:

```
this.showSlides[slideNo] = true
```

I now use this Vue.js syntax:

```
this.$set(this.showSlides, slideNo, true)
```

My solution was inspired by this article:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats